# What is the meaning of the idiom "Discedere ab amicis"

Tags: idiom

I found this in a [Latin-English dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_copious_dictionary_in_three_parts_I_Th/aYnCSAgRrwMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20leave%20the%20friendship%20of%20men%22&pg=RA13-PA1&printsec=frontcover). Is the specific meaning known? The English translation does not give me any specifics in terms of the meaning. I was thinking it could mean self-isolation or even suicide.

[image]

Comment: The Latin means pretty much literally what the English says: to distance oneself from one's friends. Are you asking if it also had a separate, idiomatic usage in Latin, meaning something like suicide?

Comment: Yes, or some other form of separating oneself from society

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means pretty much literally that: to abandon one's friends, to break off a friendship, either permanently or temporarily. Cicero uses it a few times in *De Amicitia* (12.42, 20.75):

> …si in eius modi amicitias ignari casu aliquo inciderint, ne existiment ita se alligatos, ut **ab amicis** in magna aliqua re publica peccantibus non **discedant**…
> *If unknowing people fall by some happenstance into friendships of this sort, they must not consider themselves to be so constrained that they cannot **separate themselves from friends** who are causing problems in important government affairs…*

> Et saepe incidunt magnae res, ut **discedendum sit ab amicis**; quas qui impedire volt, quod desiderium non facile ferat…
> *And often important matters come up where one must **be separated from their friends**; someone who wants to obstruct these matters because they cannot easily bear this grief…[is weak-willed and also a bad friend]*

I don't think it was a special idiom, though, because Cicero uses plenty of synonyms too. When talking about ending friendships in the next paragraph (21), he uses *demittere amicitiam* instead.